# How to fix a IAM assume issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am not able to fix a IAM issue. When I am trying to assume role from my Jenkins machine I keep getting this error.

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: User: arn:aws:sts::1111111111:assumed-role/jenkins/i-0534a6823420911ae is not authorized to perform: sts:AssumeRole on resource: arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/eks-controller
```

I created a Role1 (Jenkins) and attached it to the ec2machine in account 1111111111 now I wanted to assume Role2 (eks-controller)
Jenkins policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "assumeEKScontroller",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::22222222222:role/eks-controller"
        }
    ]
}
```

Role eks-controller is in account 22222222222 with below-trusted policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:root"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

How does assumerole work? I read a lot of articles and tried but nothing is working.

Comment: Can you try to check it manually? Assume the role using AWS STS cli on this or some new instance.

Comment: @Marcin Tired manually as well. Getting the same error.